# Getting the difference between current column and previous column to current column

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have the following table in SQL

```
Date            Time       Value
======================================
01/01/2020    00:05:00      10
01/01/2020    10:05:00      20
01/01/2020    20:05:00      35
02/01/2020    00:05:00      10
02/01/2020    10:05:00      15
02/01/2020    20:05:00      35
```

Want to add a new column to find the difference between the current row value with previous row value for a day like below

```
Date            Time       Value   New_Value
=============================================
01/01/2020    00:05:00      10      10
01/01/2020    10:05:00      20      10  (20-10)
01/01/2020    20:05:00      35      15  (35-25)
02/01/2020    00:05:00      10      10
02/01/2020    10:05:00      15      5   (15-10)
02/01/2020    20:05:00      35      20  (35-15)
```

Can this be achieved in SQL without introducing any new columns.

Comment: I don't think you actually want to do `ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN` - I think you just want a `VIEW`.

Comment: How to get the difference from current row value to previous row value. do you have any idea ?

Comment: Anyway, use `LAG` and `LEAD` for this - also tables do not have a meaningful sort-order: there is no concept of a "previous row" in an RDBMS - instead you have to provide an explicit `ORDER BY` clause for the `OVER` window.

Comment: ...dare I ask why your `date` and `time` columns are... separate columns? Is there a _good reason_ why you aren't using a singular `datetime2(7)` or `datetimeoffset(7)` column instead?

Comment: These table is an already existing structure and it is being used for different filtering purpose. if needed it can be modified

Comment: Are you familiar with `VIEW` objects and table-valued functions? (kinda-similar-ish to `PROCEDURE` but also very different in its own way)

Comment: Okay @Dai, will look into VIEW as well

Answer (score 0):

One of your methods is to use Lag and create a view

```
create view vw_tt
as 
select *,  value-lag(value) over (
partition by date  order by(CAST(Date AS datetime) + CAST(Time AS datetime)))  as New_Value

from tt
```

Example data:

```
create table tt(Date date,time time(0),value int)

insert into tt(Date,Time,Value)
values ('01/01/2020',    '00:05:00',      10) ,('01/01/2020',    '10:05:00',      20),('01/01/2020',    '20:05:00',      35)
,('02/01/2020',    '00:05:00',      10),('02/01/2020',    '10:05:00',      15),('02/01/2020',    '20:05:00',      35)
```